# Is that js expression safe: if( !x || doSomething( x[prop], y[prop] ) === false )

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression

From a bug report, I think that the following expression might throw an exception if x is null:

```
if ( !x || doSomething( x[prop], y[prop] ) === false )
```

The exception is:

> Cannot read property 'prop' of null

... as if the right side of the || is evaluated even if the left side is true.
The [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) seems to indicate that that should not happen, but I'm not sure. I've tested that just writing x = null does not (always) crash, but is it guaranteed on every JS engine ?

EDIT:

Same question about

```
if( x && foo( x[prop] ) === true && bar() === false )
```

One way to put it is, does :

if( a && b && c )

... evaluates b or c if a === false ? The doc is not clear about that case, only for "a && ( expr1 && expr2 )", not "a && expr1 && expr2"

Full code snippet

```js
var x = null;
var y = {
  "p1": "p1",
  "p2": "p2"
};

function f() {
  return true;
}

for (var propName in y) {

  if (x && f(y[propName]) === true && f(y[propName]) === false) {
    doSomething(x[propName], y[propName]);
  } else if (!x || f(x[propName], y[propName]) === false) {
    console.log(y[propName]);
  }
}
```

EDIT2: for completeness, the real (minimized) code that run in the browser

```
  function a(c, b, e, f) {

        for (var d in b) {
          if (c && _.isObject(b[d]) === true && _.isArray(b[d]) === false) {
            a(c[d], b[d], e, d + ".")
          } else {
            if (!c || _.isEqual(c[d], b[d]) === false) {
              e.push({
                name: f + d,
                value: b[d]
              })
            }
          }
        }
        return e
      }
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle with sample? are you sure that x is null? are you sure that exception in this line?

Comment: Use `if (x && y && x.hasOwnProperty(prop) && y.hasOwnProperty(prop) && doSomething(x[prop], y[prop]) === false)`

Comment: so, you should check _y_ also!

Comment: You do a check on `x` but not on `y`.

Comment: @Tushar `foo.hasOwnProperty('bar')` is not the same as "can I [[GET]] _bar_ from `foo`?" Instead, `('bar' in foo)` is more reliable

Comment: Documentation says: ["The rules of logic guarantee that these evaluations are always correct. Note that the anything part of the above expressions is not evaluated ..."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation)

Comment: We don't really know if OP wants to check properties on the prototype chain or just the object, so it could be any.

Comment: I'm sure that y is not null because the code is in a loop:
for( var prop in y)

Comment: I have a feeling the error isn't here, unless `y` has a property named 'prop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Is it guaranteed on every JS engine?"

We can't actually know that for sure, but the standard defines, how these operators should be implemented.

Logical OR:

> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating **LogicalORExpression**.
> 2. Let *lval* be **GetValue(lref)**.
> 3. If **ToBoolean(lval)** is **true**, return *lval*.
> 4. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating **LogicalANDExpression**.
> 5. Return **GetValue(rref)**.

http://es5.github.io/#x11.11

Item 3 doesn't leave any room to doubts, *lval* is returned immediately if *lref* can be evaluated to truthy, and *rref* will never be evaluated.

Comment: so there's no doubt about "(a || b===c)", b===c should not be evaluated. I'm still not sure about ( a && b && c ) with a===false, are b or c evaluated ?

Comment: @Ilya If you'd put the parents to the expression to show the correct execution order (`( (a && b) && c )`), then you'd see. If `a===false`, `b` or `c` can be even not defined at all.

Comment: OK, so the exception in that code is still a mystery to me. It happened, seemingly randomly, inside that function, and testing the x == null case beforehand seemed to fix the problem. Very strange.

Comment: @Ilya Based on what you've posted, it's impossible to even speculate a reason for random errors. Maybe you should ask a new question about your real problem, include the code defining `x` and the "loop", and include also the source of "bug report".

Comment: I've added the code with the loop in the question. The bug report is a log of browser (Chrome) exceptions including the stack trace. So I'm sure that the exception is in the loop, in the if() or the else(), from one of the [propName] expressions, because x is null. So the real problem is fully contained in the loop: according to my understanding of the JS standard, a null x shouldn't trigger an exception because the x[propName] should not be evaluated.

Comment: @Ilya Like I said, please ask a __new__ question. Asking about JS behavior and about errors randomly occuring in some code are totally diffrerent subjects.

Answer (score 3):

The Javascript `||` operator is short-circuiting. The right-hand side will not evaluate if the left-hand side is `true`. That's a fundamental property of the operator and should be equally implemented across all engines.

Therefore, the right-hand side will only evaluate if `x` is *truthy*, and all truthy values in Javascript should be subscriptable without error.

Having said that, `y` is completely unknown in this example and might throw an error.

Comment: > y is completely unknown in this example and might throw an error


@deceze Yes "y" somewhat obscures the question, I should haved removed it as it's always not null

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof y != 'undefined' && typeof x != 'undefined' && x !== null && y !== null) {
   if (doSomething( x[prop], y[prop] ) === false) {
       //do stuff
   }
}
```

do the safety check before. this should be working

but **note**:

if your `prop` Attribute does not exist, this will return an error too!

greetings