# I'd like to make sense of a JS nullreference exception

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, underscore.js, nullreferenceexception

An exception occurred several times inside the following function, running in the (Chrome) browsers of our users. NB the code is minified, I've just added newlines for readabilily.

```
  function a(c, b, e, f) {
    for (var d in b) {
      if (c && _.isObject(b[d]) === true && _.isArray(b[d]) === false) {
        a(c[d], b[d], e, d + ".")
      } else {
        if (!c || _.isEqual(c[d], b[d]) === false) {
          e.push({
            name: f + d,
            value: b[d]
          })
        }
      }
    }
    return e
  }
```

The exception was: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'beginning' of null`

So far my analysis is this:

1. Known fact: `beginning` is one of the values of the `d` variable (a
   property of `b`).
2. So, the exception occurred when evaluating `b[d]`or `c[d]`
3. Inside the `for` loop, `c` can be null, but not `b` (b null => no loop)
4. So, the only way to trigger that exception is to have a `null` `c`
5. If `c` is `null`, we have to take the `else` path
6. If `c` is `null`, `!c` is truthy, so `_.isEqual(...)` should **not** be evaluated (see [Is that js expression safe: if( !x || doSomething( x[prop], y[prop] ) === false )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358276/is-that-js-expresion-safe-if-x-dosomething-xprop-yprop-false/34360573#34360573)).

At that point, I've reached a dead end in my reasoning. The exception should not happen. I probably made a mistake somewhere along the line, but where ?

NB: the problem *seems* to be fixed (I can't reproduce it, so I can't be sure), just by changing the code a bit, adding a separate 'is c null ?' test before the if...else, but that's not very satisfying.

Comment: Add console lines to get a better idea on where it is failing.

Comment: Have some sort of console through which you can track where it breaks exactly. It'll be easier to debug.

Comment: the issue is with `c[d]`, after the first recursion, which is assumed to be something, but it's not always something just because `b[d]` is something

Comment: @dandavis see point 5 and 6. Don't you agree ?

Comment: @epascarello: I don't have access to the user's browser, only the stack trace of the exception logged on the server.

Comment: is c a boolean? , if c IS a boolean and its null it will go to the else path and when its called in the other if it wont work since !c is calling a null not false or true, doesnt it works like that?

Comment: @ivan c is not a boolean in the first `a()` call, but even if it was at some point, I think the question is the same.

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005286/check-if-null-boolean-is-true-results-in-exception

Comment: @ivan this is javascript, not java